# Autoincrement a date in a formula when dragging horizontally

Tags: google-sheets

I have a date in column A, and a formula in column B that references the date. I'm trying to drag the formula over to 6 more cells horizontally, representing the 7 days of the week, Column A being Sunday's date, and Column B being Monday's date. I could technically just have 6 distinct formulas where it's Column A's date value+1, +2...+6. But that's a pain in the butt. Is there a way to autoincrement the value being added?

Here's exactly what I have:
[image: formula example]

Comment: So the formula in Column C when doing this manually would be $A2 + 1, Column D would be $A2 + 2, and so forth until Column H which would be $A2 + 6. Given that I need to replicate this for every week in the year, I'm hoping there is an easier way. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with one formula entered in cell A2:

```
=arrayformula(date(2016,5,21) + 7*(row(A2:G)-2) + column(A2:G)-1)
```

Here, `date(2016,5,21)` is the date you want to begin your calendar with. The term `7*(row(A2:G)-2)` increments the date by 7 for each row after the 2nd one (since you begin with A2). The term `column(A2:G)-1` increments by 1 for each column after the 1st one.

You'll also need to choose the desired date format for the range A2:G.

This list of dates will automatically expand if you add more rows to the sheet.